# Is it possible to use/extract the type used by a generic to define a second generic's type?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I know the title may be a little unclear, so I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

> Note, this is more for educational reasons around the language's capabilities.  In other words *if* this is possible, not *should* this be the way to go about it.

Consider the following generic class:

```
public class Foo<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now consider concrete subclasses based on the above.  Here's two examples using 'int' and 'string'...

```
public class IntFoo : Foo<int>
{
}

public class StrFoo : Foo<string>
{
}
```

And finally a generic that takes a Foo as a type parameter, and inherits from a Laa which takes its type parameter from Foo.

```
public class BaseClass<TFoo, TFooId> : Laa<TFooId>
{
}

public class Laa<TFooId>
{
}
```

Here's how you'd do the one based on an int and string, but note in addition to IntFoo and StrFoo, I have to also define int and foo explicitly...

```
public class IntFinal : BaseClass<IntFoo, int>
{
    char somePropSpecificToIntFinal{ get; set; }
}

public class StrFinal : BaseClass<StrFoo, string>
{
    char somePropSpecificToStrFinal{ get; set; }
}
```

> Note that these 'final' classes are concrete types with their own properties which can't be reduced to a generic that takes a type (i.e. using a generic with the single type T, that then subclasses another generic that takes Foo and T as its arguments.

I'm wondering is if there's a way to have that type inferred so it can be written like so...

```
public class IntFinal : BaseClass<IntFoo>
{
}

public class StrFinal : BaseClass<StrFoo>
{
}
```

...and have the type for Laa implied from the generic specified on Foo.  Here's a pseudo-code example of what I want.

```
public class BaseClass<TFoo> : Laa<TFoo.IdType>
{
}
```

So is that possible in C#?

Note, if this can't be done with classes, can it be done with interfaces?

Consider this...

```
interface IFoo
{
    Type FoosType { get; }
}

public class Foo<TId> : Foo
{
    TId Id { get; set; }

    Type FoosType { get{ return TId } }
}
```

Then do this...

```
public class BaseClass<TFoo> : Laa<TFoo.FoosType>
where TFoo : Foo
{
}
```

(Note: FoosType would have to be static technically, and you can't inherit using statics so again, this is pseudo-code.)

If you constrained TFoo to IFoo, could you then use 'FoosType' as the type specifier when defining Laa?

Comment: I think I've seen some implementation like that. But NOT SURE.

Comment: I think You should be able to handle this with Where clause (where IntFoo : Int32) or (where IntFoo : INumeric) - idea is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb384067%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: No, i'm not restricting it to numerics.  I'm trying to get whatever type Foo<T> is using.  I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: you can have final generic class `public class Final<T> : BaseClass<Foo<T>, T>` how ever in this case you should forget about non generic `IntFoo` and `StrFoo` and try to implement them in generic way.

Comment: Good point, but that's the problem when you try to simplify samples.  I need the concrete IntFoo and StrFoo because they each have unique properties.  In actuality, they are CategoryRow and ComponentRow, both of which are based on DBRow<TId> where TId is an int in this case, but may be a GUID in another. I'm building a caching mechanism that retrieves based on that ID (Laa<T> is really Cache<T>).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that based on the C# specification. Type inference currently works for methods only and doesn't work for types (classes like your case)

Second rule that breaks your needed result is that you can't specify one generic type argument and infer the other, it is **Provide all or Infer all** case for methods.

C# specification:

> 1.6.3 Type parameters
>
> When the generic class is used, type arguments must be provided for each of the type parameters

Comment: But wouldn't what I'm asking be providing it explicitly?  I'm not inferring anything for the reasons you mentioned. In other words, if I'm defining a generic, can I grab the type that's passed to it to pass to the base class.  Actually... I just had an idea!  Back in a minute...

Comment: @MarqueIV No you're not providing it explicitly. If a class needs 2 type arguments, you must specify these two: `Foo<T, V>`. You can't specify `T` and have `V` be inferred by the compiler through some other way. This is the language specification.

Comment: We're saying different things.  If you have Foo with a property Laa, and you're passed a Foo, you can grab Laa and pass it to something else explicitly.  That's essentially what I was asking except instead of a property, it would have been an *already explicitly passed-in type*. Nothing was implicit.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very specific, and it's not clear what the actual constraints and requirements are. That said…

Type inference only occurs for generic methods, not generic types. So taking your question literally, the answer is no, there is no way to infer the type.

What *might* work for you is to use `Foo<TId>` in the class definition instead of `IntFoo`:

```
class BaseClass<TFooId> : Laa<TFooId>
{
    public Foo<TFooId> Method() { ... }
}
```

(Of course, you can apply the type anywhere appropriate: fields, property types, etc.)

I.e. instead of coding the `BaseClass` type with two type parameters, just use the one that uniquely defines the interesting/useful elements of the `Foo<TFooId>` base class you're using, and then use that base type instead of the more-derived `IntFoo`

In your example, you have no constraints for the `TFoo` class, so it's not like `BaseClass<TFoo, TFooId>` was going to be able to use even the base type class members from `Foo<TId>` anyway. But even if you did mean to constrain `TFoo` to `Foo<TFooId>`, it seems likely you wouldn't really need to specify that type anyway.

If the above is not useful, then you need to add a lot more detail to your question, to explain precisely what is needed. Consider also that it's likely people have already gone down this road, and that if you express your question less about the mechanics of the implementation you *think* you need, you instead phrase it at a higher level, you might likely find existing questions on Stack Overflow or articles elsewhere that already address that broader question.

At the very least, if you are unable to find such references yourself, expressing your question that way may yield better answers faster.

See also [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, I have already addressed why I can't use the base class implementation you stated (using a single type rather than the two-type generic.)  And as for explaining the specifics, the question would be much longer than this and isn't really what I was after anyway which was to see if you can extract the type from something that inherits from a generic.  I believe the answer is no, but there are always parts of the language you don't know where someone else does, so I asked.  Thanks for your critique though.  We're just looking at two different things.